# how could I pass this query in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
SELECT lamparas.id,lampara, contenedor_id, contenedor, encendido_apagado, lamparas.estado 
FROM lamparas 
INNER JOIN contenedores ON lamparas.contenedor_id = contenedores.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Laravel 8 and Eloquent you could try something like:

```
$results = DB::table('lamparas')
            ->join('contenedores', 'lamparas.contenedor_id', '=', 'contenedores.id')
            ->select('lamparas.id', 'lampara', 'contenedor_id', 'contenedor', 'encendido_apagado', 'lamparas.estado')
            ->get();
```

You should really have a read of the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries